# Why use the notion $R\cap (C\times C)$ to mean the induced relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *Daniel W. Cunningham. “Set Theory: A First Course.”*, the author uses the notation $R_{\mathcal{C}}$ to denote the induced relation on $\mathcal{C}$. Specifically, let $R$ is a relation on set $A$ and $C \subseteq A$, the relation induced on $C$ is defined to be:

$$R_{\mathcal{C}}=R\cap (C\times C)\text{ ,}$$

Even though, the author explicitly explains the equation means that:

$$
x R_{\mathcal{C}} y \leftrightarrow x \in \mathcal{C}, y \in \mathcal{C}\text{ and }x R_{\mathcal{C}} y
$$

I can't see why it's translated that way (suppose $C=\{x, y\}$, then $C\times C=\{(x, x), (x, y), (y, x), (y, y)\}$, and so $\cap (C \times C) = \emptyset$?).

Comment: The author restricts the domain of $R$ defined on $A$ to a subset $C$ of $A$

Comment: You have to consider a Relation on e.g. $A = \{ x,y,z \}$ and then restrict it to $C = \{ x,y \}$.

Comment: I understand that. What I can't understand is why $\cap (C\times C)$ is used and translated into $x \in C \text{ and } y \in C$, I can't wrap my mind around it?

Comment: It is the intersection of $R$ (a set of pairs) with the cartesian product $C \times C$ (a set of pairs). It is not $\bigcap (C \times C)$

Comment: Ohm, it is what I misunderstood. Thanks!